# Convertir fraccion impropia a mixta en java

Tags: java

Necesito convertir una fraccion impropia a mixta en java. Este es el código que tengo hecho hasta ahora.

```
public String ShowWithInt(Racional r){
       String res="";
       if(r.getDenominador()>r.getNumerador())
           res="No se puede simplificar";
       else{

       }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: Buenas Mario. Has de explicar mejor lo que intentas. Pon ejemplos de inputs y el output esperado asi como el resultado actrual que estás teniendo o los errores cocnretos. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes verificar que se trate de una fracción impropia, las fracciones impropias son aquellas en que el numerador es mayor que el denominador. Para convertir una fracción impropia en mixta, debes obtener tanto el resultado como el resto de la división entre el numerador y el denominador.

```
public String ShowWithInt(Racional r){
       String res="";
       if(r.getDenominador()>=r.getNumerador())
           res="Es una fracción propia";
       else{
            int numerador = r.getNumerador();
            int denominador = r.getDenominador();
            int resultado = numerador / denominador;
            int resto = numerador % denominador;
            res = resultado+" "+resto+"/"+denominador;
       }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero las respuestas que son  solo codigo no son utiles más que para copiar y pegar. Has de explicar cómo funciona. Aunque es mejor esperar a que el autor muestre su problema concreto y no resolverle la tarea. Un saludo

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el habia colocado un fragmento de código y al realizar una edición lo borro. Saludos.

Comment: Si, pero aun con el codigo, no explica su problema. No dice lo que pretende, el resultado esperado , el resultado actual, codigo de error.. etc